# How to use procedure parameters variable in query inside procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a procedure to backup a table in mysql.

My Code is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `backup_table`(current_name VARCHAR(50), backup_name VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE `@backup_name` LIKE `@current_name`;
    INSERT INTO `@backup_name` SELECT * FROM `@current_name`;
END $$
DELIMITER;

CALL backup_table('users', 'users_bak');
```

Procedure created successfully but when I'm trying to call that procedure with my table names as parameter, it throws error:

```
Query : call backup_table('users', 'users_bak')
Error Code : 1146
Table 'database.@current_name' doesn't exist
```

I've used procedure without @ sign also but not worked.

So, tell me, how to use arguments variable in query as table name.
Please help me guys!!!!

Comment: You can't use table name as a paramter without dynamyc sql.

Comment: The following section of the documentation will be helpful: [13.5. SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Thanks @wchiquito, prepare statement works great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys!

I've resolved my question myself with the help of @wchiquito's help comment for sql prepare statement.

See code below:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `backup_table`(current_name VARCHAR(50), backup_name VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN 
    SET @ct = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', backup_name, ' LIKE ', current_name);
    SET @it = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', backup_name, ' SELECT * FROM ', current_name);
    PREPARE create_t FROM @ct;
    EXECUTE create_t;
    PREPARE insert_t FROM @it;
    EXECUTE insert_t;
END;


CALL backup_table('users', 'users_bak');
```

I'm posting answer because,
May be this will help some another too!!!